# How to get Jenkins to report after the build script fails?

Tags: rake, jenkins

I use rake to build my project and one of the steps is running the unit, integration and fitnesse tests.  If too many of these fail, I fail the rake script.

That part is working fine.

Unfortunately, after the build is failed, jenkins doesn't publish the html reports I generated from the unit, integration and fitnesse tests I generated, making it tad difficult to track down the failure reason.

Am I missing a configuration step to get the reports published?

Is Jenkins supposed to skip the post-build steps when the build fails?
It seems like it some for most of the plugins I am using.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally figured it out, one of those I could have had a V8 moments...

I'm using a rake file to build and one of it's tasks is failing just before some reporting tasks that need to run in order to have the HTML pushed into the correct area to be published.

Comment: I thought that was a given. But what's the actual fix, to always get it to publish the HTML report?!

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell Jenkins which artifacts to archive in a post-build step (there is a check box under general 'Post-build actions' heading which is called 'Archive the Artifacts'). Important: the artifact path is determined relative to the workspace directory. Make sure that the option *Discard all but the last successful/stable artifact to save disk space* is not checked.

Comment: I've tried that and it did not work.  One of my post build steps is Publish HTML reports.  For one of the reports the 3 parameters are: \TestResults\UnitCoverageReports, fullcoveragereport.html, Unit Test Coverage Report.  Keep past HTML reports is checked and when I look on disk the reports are there, but the links for the report are not on the job.  If the build succeeds the links are there.  If the build is unstable they are there.  If the build fails, no links.

Comment: What if you archive them by hand in 'Archive the Artifacts' step, not in 'Publish HTML reports' step, does it work? I remember trying using that plugin, but giving up on it - don't remember exactly why.

Comment: I did try the archive the Artifacts step independent of the HTML part.   That's what I meant by it not working.  The files are in the new and old build folders.  Only thing missing is the HTML links on the main build page.  Through the file system I bring up all the reports.  Is Jenkins supposed to skip the post-build steps when the build fails?

Comment: It's supposed to archive the artifacts regardless. Make sure that the option _Discard all but the last successful/stable artifact to save disk space_ is not checked. When you say 'main build page', do you mean `http://[server]/job/[job_name]/[job_num]/` page?

Comment: I've run some tests just in case - the artifacts are archived regardless of whether the build is successful or not. There is only one thing I can think about beside the particulars of your set-up - updating plugins/Jenkins.